# Multi-step assembly with webpack

Tags: webpack, pug

Task:

1. merge all pug files (blocks/*.pug) into one (blocks.pug)
2. compile index.pug that contains blocks.pug

Everything works fine, but there's a problem.
The assembly goes so fast that does not have time to read the created blocks.pug file:

*Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open blocks.pug*

So, i have to run the assembly again to avoid this error and i get the correct index.html

Is there a way to do all these steps in one pass?

My webpack.config.js

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
      HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
let extractPug = new ExtractTextPlugin({filename: '../src/blocks/blocks.pug', allChunks: true});

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
            enforce: 'pre',
            test: /\.pug$/,
            exclude: /\/blocks\/index.pug$/,
            loader: extractPug.extract('raw')
        }, {
            test: /\.pug$/,
            include: /\/blocks\/index.pug$/,
            loader: 'html!pug-html?pretty'
        },
        ...
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        extractPug,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: './blocks/index.pug',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ]
};
```

Sorry if i wrote something unclear, my English isn't good enough.